# (HTML/CSS) cannot get blocks to line up one after the other with text underneath

Tags: html, css

i am a beginner with html and css so apologies for any silly mistakes. i have been working on a design for a music blog and i wanted to have a list of album covers with text underneath them lined up one after the other, to the right of a "review" section. [Better explained by the wireframe i designed for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpcZC.png)

however, ive been fiddling around with it and i cannot seem to get it right, i believe the problem is with my CSS. right now it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KHxi.png)

the html is as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
    @import url("yeyeyyey.css");
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="reviewsection">
        <div class="reviews"><a href="reviews.html">reviews.</a></div>
        <ul class="reviewsimg">
            <li class="albumart"><a class="album" href="#"><img class="albumartspace" src="Sample-Logo-square-300x300.png" alt="Warehouse Project"></a></li>
                <ul class="albumdetails">
                    <li class="artistname">Artist Name</li>
                    <li class="albumname"><a class="album">Album Name</a></li>
                    <ul class="edited">
                        <li class="author">Author /</li>
                        <li class="genre"> Genre </li>
                        <li class="lastedited">/ Last Edited</li>
                    </ul>
                    <li class="albumsummary"><p>[summary of album]</p></li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    </section>

    <section class="releasesection">
      <div class="releasecalendar"><a href="releasecalendar.html">release calendar.</a></div>
        <ul class="calendarimg">
            <ul class="artandtext">
                <li class="calendarart"><a class="calendaralbum" href="#"><img class="calendarartspace" src="Sample-Logo-square-300x300.png" alt="Album"></a></li>
                <li class="releasedate">Release Date</li>
                <li class="name">Artist Name</li>
                <li class="albumtitle">Album Title</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="artandtext">
                <li class="calendarart"><a class="calendaralbum" href="#"><img class="calendarartspace" src="Sample-Logo-square-300x300.png" alt="Album"></a></li>
                <li class="releasedate">Release Date</li>
                <li class="name">Artist Name</li>
                <li class="albumtitle">Album Title</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="artandtext">
                <li class="calendarart"><a class="calendaralbum" href="#"><img class="calendarartspace" src="Sample-Logo-square-300x300.png" alt="Album"></a></li>
                <li class="releasedate">Release Date</li>
                <li class="name">Artist Name</li>
                <li class="albumtitle">Album Title</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="artandtext">
                <li class="calendarart"><a class="calendaralbum" href="#"><img class="calendarartspace" src="Sample-Logo-square-300x300.png" alt="Album"></a></li>
                <li class="releasedate">Release Date</li>
                <li class="name">Artist Name</li>
                <li class="albumtitle">Album Title</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="artandtext">
                <li class="calendarart"><a class="calendaralbum" href="#"><img class="calendarartspace" src="Sample-Logo-square-300x300.png" alt="Album"></a></li>
                <li class="releasedate">Release Date</li>
                <li class="name">Artist Name</li>
                <li class="albumtitle">Album Title</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

the CSS is as follows:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* REVIEWS */

body {
    font-family: courier;
}

.reviewsection {
    float: left;
    width:35%;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.reviews {display:inline-block;
             padding-top: 10px}

.reviews a {
    color: black; 
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    background-color: white;
}

.reviews a:hover {
    background-color: black; 
    color:white;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.reviewsimg {
    display:flex;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 350px;
    margin-top: -13px;
    list-style: none;
}

.albumartspace {
    width:100%;
    max-width:250px;
    height:auto;
}

.albumart {
    margin-top:22px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

.albumart img:hover {
    opacity: .8;
}

.albumdetails {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    list-style: none;
}

.artistname {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.albumname {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.edited {
    padding-left:0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-style: italic;
}

.author {
    display: inline;
}

.genre {
    display: inline;
    color: red;
}

.lastedited {
    display: inline;
    color: grey;
}

/* RELEASE CALENDAR */

.releasesection {
    float:left;
    width:42%;
    height:auto;
}

.releasecalendar {
    display:block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.releasecalendar a {
    color: white; 
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    background-color: black;
}

.releasecalendar a:hover {
    background-color: white; 
    color:black;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.calendarimg {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.artandtext {
    display:inline;
    width:20%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

.calendarart {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    list-style-image: none;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.calendarartspace {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're wasting you're own time trying to write the CSS for spacing this all out manaully.

Have a look at Bootstrap's [grid documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/layout/grid/) where making a grid layout becomes as easy as:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is responsive out of the box, so things automatically stack correctly on a smaller device like a phone or tablet.

Getting started with this is as simple as including the CDN hosted Bootstrap.css in the `<head>` section of your own page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap-grid.css" integrity="sha256-HRLYo6FLXIvFal6HYY2xyKFHJdB/vl4JQDg4fVhGujA=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

You might need some JS plugins later on if you want to add some more advanced bootstrap functionality.

Comment: Listen to this guy. I wasted loads of time creating my own CSS only to realise that someone had done the hard work first.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are aiming at in detail, but a basic problem you are having is that you are using a lot of `ul` and `li` elements, which have default margins and paddings. So if you just reset that like this...

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

...that's a big step forward. Next step is to fine-tune widths etc.

```css
@charset "utf-8";
/* REVIEWS */

body {
    font-family: courier;
}
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.reviewsection {
    float: left;
    width:35%;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.reviews {display:inline-block;
             padding-top: 10px}

.reviews a {
    color: black; 
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    background-color: white;
}

.reviews a:hover {
    background-color: black; 
    color:white;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.reviewsimg {
    display:flex;
    padding:0px;
    background-color:white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 350px;
    margin-top: -13px;
    list-style: none;
}

.albumartspace {
    width:100%;
    max-width:250px;
    height:auto;
}

.albumart {
    margin-top:22px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

.albumart img:hover {
    opacity: .8;
}

.albumdetails {
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    list-style: none;
}

.artistname {
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.albumname {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.edited {
    padding-left:0px;
    list-style-type: none;
    font-style: italic;
}

.author {
    display: inline;
}

.genre {
    display: inline;
    color: red;
}

.lastedited {
    display: inline;
    color: grey;
}

/* RELEASE CALENDAR */

.releasesection {
display: inline-block;    width:60%;
    height:auto;
}

.releasecalendar {
    display:block;
    padding-top: 10px;
    float: left;
}

.releasecalendar a {
    color: white; 
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 0px 5px;
    background-color: black;
}

.releasecalendar a:hover {
    background-color: white; 
    color:black;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.calendarimg {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    margin-left: 0px;
}

.artandtext {
    display:inline-block;
    width:19%;
    height:auto;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
}

.calendarart {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    list-style-image: none;
    margin-right: 0px;
}

.calendarartspace {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin-right: 0px;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
    @import url("yeyeyyey.css");
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="reviewsection">
        <div class="reviews"><a href="reviews.html">reviews.</a></div>
        <ul class="reviewsimg">
            <li class="albumart"><a class="album" href="#"><img class="albumartspace" src="https://placehold.it/300x300/ccc" alt="Warehouse Project"></a></li>
                <ul class="albumdetails">
                    <li class="artistname">Artist Name</li>
                    <li class="albumname"><a class="album">Album Name</a></li>
                    <ul class="edited">
                        <li class="author">Author /</li>
                        <li class="genre"> Genre </li>
                        <li class="lastedited">/ Last Edited</li>
                    </ul>
                    <li class="albumsummary"><p>[summary of album]</p></li>
                </ul>
        </ul>
    </section>

    <section class="releasesection">
      <div class="releasecalendar"><a href="releasecalendar.html">release calendar.</a></div>
        <ul class="calendarimg">
            <ul class="artandtext">
                <li class="calendarart"><a class="calendaralbum" href="#"><img class="calendarartspace" src="https://placehold.it/300x300/ccc" alt="Album"></a></li>
                <li class="releasedate">Release Date</li>
                <li class="name">Artist Name</li>
                <li class="albumtitle">Album Title</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="artandtext">
                <li class="calendarart"><a class="calendaralbum" href="#"><img class="calendarartspace" src="https://placehold.it/300x300/ccc" alt="Album"></a></li>
                <li class="releasedate">Release Date</li>
                <li class="name">Artist Name</li>
                <li class="albumtitle">Album Title</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="artandtext">
                <li class="calendarart"><a class="calendaralbum" href="#"><img class="calendarartspace" src="https://placehold.it/300x300/ccc" alt="Album"></a></li>
                <li class="releasedate">Release Date</li>
                <li class="name">Artist Name</li>
                <li class="albumtitle">Album Title</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="artandtext">
                <li class="calendarart"><a class="calendaralbum" href="#"><img class="calendarartspace" src="https://placehold.it/300x300/ccc" alt="Album"></a></li>
                <li class="releasedate">Release Date</li>
                <li class="name">Artist Name</li>
                <li class="albumtitle">Album Title</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="artandtext">
                <li class="calendarart"><a class="calendaralbum" href="#"><img class="calendarartspace" src="https://placehold.it/300x300/ccc" alt="Album"></a></li>
                <li class="releasedate">Release Date</li>
                <li class="name">Artist Name</li>
                <li class="albumtitle">Album Title</li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```